# Applying a lambda function to a column got failed in pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I don't know why the index method has inconsistent behavior while doing column-wise apply function.

The data frame is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( [(1, 'Hello'), (2, "World")])
df.columns=['A', 'B']
```

And I want to apply lambda to the second columns, it it saying the Series object can not be apply?

```
print df.iloc[:, 1:2].apply(lambda x: x.upper()).head()
 **AttributeError**:("'Series' object has no attribute 'upper'", u'occurred at index B')
print df.loc[:, ['B']].apply(lambda x: x.upper()).head()
 **AttributeError**:("'Series' object has no attribute 'upper'", u'occurred at index B')
```

But rather the following indexing method works well.

```
print df.loc[:, 'B'].apply(lambda x: x.upper()).head()
```

Why? I think the three index methods are equivalent?
All above three indexing method has almostly the same result if print out
that is:

```
   B
0  Hello
1  World
```

and print df.loc[:, 'B']   gets

```
0  Hello
1  World
Name: B, dtype: object
```

What do the differences mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you index with `'B'` you get a series.  When you index with `1:2` or with `['B']`, you get a DataFrame with one column.  When you use `apply` on a series, your function is called on each element.  When you use `apply` on a DataFrame, your function is called on each *column*.

So no, they aren't equivalent.  When you have a Series you can use your function as you want.  When you have a one-column DataFrame, you can't, because it gets passed the column as its argument, and the column is a Series that doesn't have an `upper` method.

You can see that they aren't the same because the results are different when you print them out.  Yes, they're *almost* the same, but not the same.  The first one has a column header, indicating that it's a DataFrame; the second has no column header but has the "Name" at the bottom, indicating it's a Series.

Answer (score 1):

As @BrenBarn mentioned, the difference is that in case of `df.iloc[:, 1:2]` you have DataFrame with one column, while in case of `df.loc[:, 'B']` you have a Series. Just a little addition, to convert DataFrame with one column into series you can use [pandas.squeeze()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html) method:

```
>>> df.iloc[:, 1:2]
       B
0  Hello
1  World
>>> df.iloc[:, 1:2].squeeze()
0    Hello
1    World
Name: B, dtype: object
```

and then you can use apply (you don't have to use `lambda`, BTW):

```
>>> df.iloc[:, 1:2].squeeze().apply(str.upper)
0    HELLO
1    WORLD
Name: B, dtype: object
```

If you want to apply `upper` to DataFrame, you can use [pandas.applymap()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/basics.html#applying-elementwise-python-functions):

```
>>> df.iloc[:, 1:2].applymap(str.upper)
       B
0  HELLO
1  WORLD
```