# Python dataframe data cleanup- normalize range of columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, normalization

I have a df with 2171 columns and 200+ rows. I want to normalize a range of those cols.

[Input df]

```
Time           '340.0'   '341.0'   '342.0'   'Mode'
11:30:15 PM    0.25       0.35      0.65      light
11:31:15 PM    0.22       0.30      0.62      auto
11:32:15 PM    0.32       0.39      0.98      auto
.
.
.
```

[Code if only used on one col, I am not sure how to apply to a range of cols]

```
sr_df['340.0'] = sr_df['340.0'].apply(lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / (x.std()))
```

I am very new to python and I am not sure why it is giving me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'mean'
```

Comment: Checkout [applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)

Comment: `sr_df['340.0'] = sr_df['340.0'].apply(lambda x: (x - sr_df['340.0'].mean()) / (sr_df['340.0'].std()))`

Comment: @jujuBee in that case, how would I do it for a range of columns? Should I use a loop? I have ~2000 columns I need normalized.

Comment: @chet-the-wizard gives me- AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'applymap'

Comment: @Brain_overflowed you apply it to the DataFrame not the column.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply your normalization on all desired columns at once:

```
sr_df[['340.0', '341.0', '342.0']].apply(lambda x: ((x-x.mean()) / (x.std())))

sr_df[['340.0', '341.0', '342.0']]= sr_df[['340.0', '341.0', '342.0']].apply(lambda x: ((x-x.mean()) / (x.std())))

>>> sr_df
          Time     340.0     341.0     342.0   Mode
0  11:30:15 PM -0.259828  0.073922 -0.500626  light
1  11:31:15 PM -0.844441 -1.034910 -0.650814   auto
2  11:32:15 PM  1.104269  0.960988  1.151440   auto
```

Better yet, you can apply it to all numeric columns (if that's what you're going for):

```
# Get a list of numeric columns:
cols = list(sr_df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).columns.values)

sr_df[cols] = sr_df[cols].apply(lambda x: ((x-x.mean()) / (x.std())))
```

## Fixing your code:

If you want to fix your code, you can apply your function on a column of your dataframe (rather than applying it on the series). The reason it doesn't work on a series is outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19782643/6671176) by @BrenBarn:

> When you use apply on a `series`, your function is called on each element. When you use apply on a `DataFrame`, your function is called on each *column*.

So the way you're doing it, you're trying to get the `mean` and `std` of a float, and floats do not have such attributes, leading to your error: `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'mean'`

```
# this works:
sr_df[['340.0']].apply(lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / (x.std()))

# This doesn't:
# sr_df['340.0'].apply(lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / (x.std()))

# The difference is this:
>>> type(sr_df['340.0'])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
>>> type(sr_df[['340.0']])
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use the [MinMaxScaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html) from [Sklean](http://scikit-learn.org). It will automatically fit/scale all values between 0 and 1. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24645153/pandas-dataframe-columns-scaling-with-sklearn) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414913/normalize-columns-of-pandas-data-frame).

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler()

columns = ['301', '341', '342'] 
df[columns] = scaler.fit_transform(df[columns])
```

Comment: That is a different scaling method than the one OP requested. Closer to the desired method is `StandardScaler` from `Sklearn` (which is the same as OP requested, except it uses the `numpy` standard for the `std` rather than the `pandas` standard, which means it uses 1 degree of freedom to calculated standard deviation rather than 0, giving slightly different results)

Comment: True. Thanks for comment.